# Is there anyway yet of disabling the Gmail labels showing in the notification area?

Tags: gmail, webapps

I know it's pre-release, so it's not finalised yet, however, I have quite the amount of labels I use for Gmail (over 20) and when I used the integration, in my notification centre I have to scroll down to use anything below the Gmail labels which is quite annoying.

Is there anyone way to stop the display on labels and only show the inbox? I ask this mainly because I don't filter to labels, each E-mail I get I assign a new label or archive, so I never have the need to see how many unread Emails are in each label.

Hope you've understood what I'm trying to say!

Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be a new feature request.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this actually besides changing the integration script to act accordingly or to be a bit more clever.

You could add a "feature request" to the launchpad page, to have more control on amount of integration (or allow scripts to define sort of "integration groups" that could be enabled/disabled).